# Raspberry Pi 3 crash after few hours running

Tags: ssh, troubleshooting, pi-3b+

I need your advice on troubleshooting my Pi 3B crashes.

I set it up to run some crypto mining programming; it was running constantly fine for over few weeks. Recently, it keeps crashing after every 5-10 hours running (unable to ssh or ping my pi locally); however, the Green Led is still blinking every 3-5 seconds.

I use a proper power supply (5v 2.5A); very good SD card Sandisk Extreme 64 Gb.

Where should I start looking?

Comment: Could you try following the steps at [Pi keeps crashing, where do I look?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/37999/58316) and [edit] to include what you find?

Comment: Try adding a heatsink and possibly a fan to your rpi: 
 https://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-install-heat-sinks-on-the-raspberry-pi

Comment: I manage to find out the issue, the power management for wifi is enabled and from time to time it shut down the wifi feature.